# Exception in Application - Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Why am i getting this exception in my Aplication ?

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = Group@f4a634[styleClass=root]
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(Unknown Source)
    at MainClass.update(MainClass.java:36)
    at MainClass.start(MainClass.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application MainClass
```

The problem is in this function :

```
 public void update(final Scene scene) {    
                final Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot(); 
                root.getChildren().add(chart);
                Timeline timeLine = new Timeline(Timeline.INDEFINITE, 
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(100),
                        x -> {                          
                            while(t < 1) {
                                final double thisT = t;
                                chart = new Chart(e -> Math.exp(-(Math.pow((e-thisT ), 2)))*Math.cos((2*Math.PI*(e-thisT))/l),
                                        -1, 1, 0.01, new Axes(1000, 1000,
                                                -1, 1, 0.1, -1, 1, 0.1)
                                        );
                                t+=0.05;    
                            }     

                        }));            
                timeLine.setAutoReverse(true);
                timeLine.setCycleCount(1000);
                timeLine.play();

       }
```

Result should be animated fade of chart starting from the left and going to the right, but if I put root.getChildren().add(chart); inside the lambda expresion i'll get another result which i wan't to. 
Chart in the last step, duplicated chart or chart in the first step. Any of those have no animation. If i undersatnd corectly adding the children should be at the beginning, and time line should work on it, if I were using swing, java i would do repaint after every update with adding the Chart, but there i can not do that. it's a liitle bit confusing me right now, becouse i can not find the good solution.

Comment: You haven't shown which line is throwing the exception, but it looks like `chart` is null when you call `root.getChildren().add(chart)`. Your code doesn't make much sense anyway; you are repeatedly creating new charts in the timeline and not doing anything with them.

Comment: Math pattern provide me to doing move my chart by changing thisT. It makes chart to the next position in the axis. Is that better way for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because the object `chart` is null at the line :

```
  root.getChildren().add(chart);
```